# no valid shader program in use, but I looked at it for 1 hour and didn't find any problems

Tags: webgl

Im  writing  a  webGL  program  that  will  generate  a  mandelbrot set.  I  get  "mandelbrot.js:33  WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION:  drawArrays:  no  valid  shader  program  in use"  even  though  the  shaders are  compiling  linking  and  validating  succsessfully.
using google chrome, and GPU: gtx 1660 ti

Vertex shader

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 position;
varying vec2 fragPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    fragPosition = position;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;
#define ITERATIONS 50

varying vec2 fragPosition;

vec2 cx_mul(vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    return vec2(a.x*b.x-a.y*b.y, a.x*b.y+a.y*b.x);
}

void main() {
    int itr = 0;
    vec2 z = fragPosition, c = fragPosition;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        itr = i;
        z = cx_mul(z, z) + c;
        if(length(z) > 2.0) break;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Javascript

```
var gl;
var canvas;
var program;
const address = '127.0.0.1';
import {initGL, compileShaders, bindVAO, loadFile} from './util.js';

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    if(!gl)
        gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    
    initGL(gl);

    var vertexCode = loadFile('http://' + address + '/mandelbrot.vert');
    var fragmentCode = loadFile('http://' + address + '/mandelbrot.frag');

    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexCode);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentCode);
    
    compileShaders(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    bindVAO();
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    update();
}

function update() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

util.js

```
export {initGL, compileShaders, bindVAO, loadFile};

var gl;

function initGL(glContext) {
    gl = glContext;
}

function compileShaders(vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
        throw ("compilation error: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
        throw ("compilation error: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS))
        throw ("linking error: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        
    gl.validateProgram(program);
    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS))
        throw ("validation error: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    
    return program;
}

function bindVAO() {
    var vertices = new Float32Array([-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1]);
    var vao = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vao);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

function loadFile(url) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uummm...

I forgot to
program = compileShaders()